# Remove prepend section when there is only one group jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

On click event, I'm cloning the section which is working fine. I also prepend the remove button when there is new section added.

I have only one issue, i want to remove the prepended button when there is only one section remain.

This is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#taskForm')
    // Add button click handler
    .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
      var $template = $('#taskTemplate'),
        $clone = $template
        .clone(true, true)
        .removeClass('hide')
        .removeAttr('id')
        .insertBefore($template);
      $('.dateofbirth').prepend($('<div style="height:0;"><a class="delete removeButton" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>'));
    })

    // Remove button click handler
    .on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
      var $row = $(this).closest('.form--group');
      $row.remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="name-field row" id="taskForm">
  <div class="form--group">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 childname">
      <div class="field text-left">
        <label class="text-left">First Name</label> <input class="“first" name="first[]" placeholder="“Firstname”" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 dateofbirth">
      <div class="field text-left">
        <label class="text-left">Date of birth</label> <input class="date" name="date[]" onkeyup="dateOfBirth(this.value,'stepbirth')" placeholder="DD / MM / JJJJ" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form--group hide" id="taskTemplate">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 childname">
        <div class="field text-left">
          <label class="text-left">First Name</label> <input class="firstname character" name="first[]" placeholder="Voornaam" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 dateofbirth">
        <div class="field text-left">
          <label class="text-left">Date of birth</label> <input class="date" name="date[]" onkeyup="dateOfBirth(this.value,'stepbirth')" placeholder="DD / MM / JJJJ" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <a class="btn-success addButton" href="#" id="addChild" name="addchild">Add Child</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with this how can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some HTML would be useful, also are you sure it is `.form--group` and not `.form-group`?

Comment: I have added the HTML, i'm using .form--group.

Comment: By the look of your example, it's not actually working properly. Your remove button is going to remove all `.form--group` as it's parent is wrapped in this class as well, you can make this work by adding in a custom index to your cloned item. The remove button also has a height of 0px so I don't see how this will show or function. And lastly you can achieve the issue you are having "i want to remove the prepended button when there is only one section remain" by using a index on your cloned items.

Comment: The "prepend" button - means the delete button, should prepend for each **new** item. Which means that when you remove the last added item, no "delete" button will left. https://jsbin.com/piratod/edit?html,js,output (With some modifications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes:

- The template should not be a *child* of the first form--group, it should be a *sibling*. If not, your dynamically added rows are regarded children of the first row. So move the template out of it, as well as the Add button.
- Do not add the HTML for the removal button via code. Instead add the HTML for that button in your static HTML, both in the first row and the template
- Every time you add or remove a row, and also at page load, perform the following action:

  ```
   $(".removeButton").toggle($(".removeButton").length > 2)
  ```

This will count the number of delete buttons (including the one that is in the template). If that counts to just two, then hide those buttons, otherwise show them.

Here is a little snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#taskForm')
      // Add button click handler
      .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
          var $template = $('#taskTemplate'),
              $clone    = $template
                              .clone(true,true)
                              .removeClass('hide')
                              .removeAttr('id')
                              .insertBefore($template);
          $(".removeButton").toggle($(".removeButton").length > 2);
      })

      // Remove button click handler
      .on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
          var $row = $(this).closest('.form--group');
          $row.remove();
          $(".removeButton").toggle($(".removeButton").length > 2);
      });
  $(".removeButton").toggle($(".removeButton").length > 2);
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none }
.field { margin-left: 20px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="name-field row" id="taskForm">
    <div class="form--group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 childname">
            <div class="field text-left">
                <label class="text-left">First Name</label> <input class="“first" name="first[]" placeholder="“Firstname”" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="height:0;"><a class="delete removeButton" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 dateofbirth">
            <div class="field text-left">
                <label class="text-left">Date of birth</label> <input class="date" name="date[]" onkeyup="dateOfBirth(this.value,'stepbirth')" placeholder="DD / MM / JJJJ" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="form--group hide" id="taskTemplate">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 childname">
            <div class="field text-left">
                <label class="text-left">First Name</label> <input class="firstname character" name="first[]" placeholder="Voornaam" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="height:0;"><a class="delete removeButton" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 dateofbirth">
            <div class="field text-left">
                <label class="text-left">Date of birth</label> <input class="date" name="date[]" onkeyup="dateOfBirth(this.value,'stepbirth')" placeholder="DD / MM / JJJJ" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <a class="btn-success addButton" href="javascript:;" id="addChild" name="addchild">Add Child</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can get here different name attribute while add the new section. something like name="first[1]", name="first[2]" or name="first[]_1", name="first[]_2"

Comment: You would use the `.attr("name", "first[" + i + "]")` where *i* is an ever increasing value. But if you cannot make it work, then ask a new question about it.